# Schwinger's Quantum Action Principle in the Schrödinger Picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, action

Schwinger's quantum action principle gives a correspondence between the variation of the action operator and transition amplitudes of operators. Has anyone ever formulated the principle in the Schrödinger picture with time-dependent states?

Answer (score 2):

[Schwinger's quantum action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%27s_quantum_action_principle) is a result about transition amplitudes, and therefore it is independent of the [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_pictures) (as different pictures are related through [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator) transformations).

Formally speaking, the operation $\delta$ is the unitary transformation generated by $\delta S$. For example,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1+\delta) |a\rangle&\equiv \mathrm e^{-i\delta S}|a\rangle\\
(1+\delta)\hat\phi&\equiv\mathrm e^{-i\delta S}\hat\phi\mathrm e^{i\delta S}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
etc.

For more details, see [DeWitt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198510934), chapter 10.

Comment: However, every publication and every text on the topic that I find is written using the Heisenberg picture, and I am not sure how exatly one would write down the variations in the schroedinger picture. but this is probably stuff for another question then.